# How do I solve $\frac{(n+2)!-n!}{5!} = 330$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial, natural-numbers

I know the answer is $n=6$, but can't figure out how to solve. 
I tried dividing by $n!$, but didn't work because there isn't one in RHS to simplify... also tried using Gamma function properties, but didn't work either...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the same as $n!\times (n^2+3n+1)=5!\times 330$.  Thus $n!$ divides $5!\times 330$ so we instantly see that $n≤6$.

Comment: I'm failing to see why $n\leq 6$

Comment: If $n>6$ then $7\,|\,n!$ but $7$ does not divide $5!\times 330$.

Comment: The asker attempted to circumvent an earlier suspension by creating their umpteenth puppet account. Account deleted. Sorry about the inconvenience caused to unsuspecting answerers. No acceptance bonus will be coming here.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by 5!.  That gives you:

$n!((n+1)(n+2)-1) = 330\cdot 5!$

So, you now have the general format of a solution. We know that $n!$ divides $330\cdot 5!$, so $n\le 6$. Trial and error will get you there quickly.

$1!(2\cdot 3-1) = 5\cdot 1! \neq 330\cdot 5!$

$2!(3\cdot 4-1) = 11\cdot 2! \neq 330\cdot 5!$

$3!(4\cdot 5-1) = 19\cdot 3! \neq 330\cdot 5!$

$4!(5\cdot 6-1) = 29\cdot 4! \neq 330\cdot 5!$

$5!(6\cdot 7-1) = 41\cdot 5! \neq 330\cdot 5!$

$6!(7\cdot 8-1) = 55\cdot 6! = 55\cdot 6\cdot 5! = 330\cdot 5!$

Comment: You should also show that the expression in increasing ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to solve for n but I do see a way to see the only solution is 6

Multiply both sides by 5! And factor out $n!$ to get the equivalent equation

$$
(n^2+3n+1)n!=55(6!)
$$

The left hand side is a strictly increasing function for $n>0$. So for any value of the right hand side, if there is a solution it is unique.

A quick check off $n=6$

$$
36+18+1=55
$$

So $n=6$ is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

Write $330 = 2\times3\times5\times11   $ & write $(n+2)!-n! = n!\times{(n^2+3n+1)}$

Clearly the RHS doesn't have 7 as its factor, so you must have $n\le6$

The other thing which we can see is that after simplification, we will be getting a quadratic equation of form $n^2 +3n-m =0$ where $m =\frac{330\times (5!)}{n!} -1$. Whatever integer $m$ might be, we need to have discriminant non-negative as well as a pure square, to have legitimate answer. As we already know, $n\le6$ and by quadratic equation, we know that $n = \frac{-3 + \sqrt D}2$, so $\sqrt D \le 15 $ means $ D\le 225$

Thus, $9+4m \le 225 $  or  $m\le54$

or  $\frac{330 \times5!}{n!} -1 \le 54 $

or  $\frac{330 \times5!}{55}\le n!$

thus $6! \le n!$

or $n\ge6$

Thus, you have only one solution n=6

Answer (score 0):

Because of $a_n = (5!)^{-1}((n+2)! - n!)$ in $\mathbb{N}$, so $n \geq 5$, and $a_n \equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for $n \geq 6$. However, $330 = 6 \cdot 55 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$ therefore $a_n = 330$ for some of $n \leq 6$. Therefore $a_n = 330$ at $n = 6$.